# Multiple value query custom fields WP

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I m trying to implement a query on my wordpress. I want display post_type "enseignement" with two filters

1. "cycle"
2. "lieu"

This code works

```
<?php if($_GET['cycle'] && !empty($_GET['cycle']))
{
$cycle = $_GET['cycle'];
} else {
}
if($_GET['lieu'] && !empty($_GET['lieu']))
{
$lieu = $_GET['lieu'];
} else {
}
?>

<?php
                $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'enseignement',
                'posts_per_page' => 10,
                'meta_query' => array(
                         'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'key' => 'cycle', // name of custom field
                            'value' => $cycle, // matches exactly "red"
                            'compare' => 'LIKE',
                                                        ),
                array(
                     'key'     => 'lieu',
                     'value'   => $lieu,
                     'compare' => 'LIKE',

         ),
    ),


                );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'enseignement', get_post_format() );?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

I have url like this this /?cycle=cycle1&lieu=paris

But if I want multiple "cycle" or multiple "lieu" like this /?cycle=cycle1,cycle2&lieu=paris,marseille I doesn't work.

How I can fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have in your url something like this:

`/?cycle[]=cycle1&cycle[]=cycle2&lieu[]=paris&lieu[]=marseille`

You will get an array in the `$_GET['cycle']` and in your `$_GET['lieu']` parameters.
[image: Visual of an array in a $_GET field]

You can pass them directly into the WP_Query args like so:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type'      => 'enseignement',
   'posts_per_page' => 10,
   'meta_query'     => array(
       'relation' => 'AND',
       array(
           'key'     => 'cycle', // name of custom field
           'value'   => $_GET['cycle'], // matches any field in the $_GET['cycle'] array
           'compare' => 'LIKE',
       ),
       array(
           'key'     => 'lieu',
           'value'   => $_GET['lieu'], // matches any field in the $_GET['lieu'] array
           'compare' => 'LIKE',
       ),
   ),
);
```